# Set vm.max_map_count for SonarQube Elastisearch in Azure Container Apps

Tags: azure, sonarqube, azure-bicep, sonarlint, azure-container-apps

I was trying to automate deployment of SonarQube enterprise edition 10.1 with connection to external database like Azure PostgreSQL flexible servers. While deployment container app is crashing, with error `max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]`

As Azure Container Apps is serverless and we cannot access OS/Kernel parameters, how do I change my `vm.max_map_count`

I am using bicep for its deployment.

This is my iac module

```
//Bicep template for deploying Container App using bicep.

@description('Provide Naming Convention parameter for the Container app')
param namingConventionProperties object = {}

@description('Provide application/resource short name for the Container app.')
param shortName string = ''

@description('Provide name for the Container app')
param resourceName string = ''

@description('Resource tags')
param tags object = {}

//TODO: JIRA PLT-28423 : We will add the support for setting userassigned Service Identity in future
@description('Type of Managed Service Identity')
@allowed([
  // 'None'
  'SystemAssigned'
  // 'SystemAssigned, UserAssgined'
  // 'UserAssgined'    //==> array of user assigned identities.
])
param identityType string = 'SystemAssigned'

@description('Container app location; default is Resource Group location')
param location string = resourceGroup().location

@description('Conatiner app enviorment name')
param containerAppEnvironmentName string

@description('Set image for your container app to use')
param containerImage string

@description('The Container app name')
param containerAppName string

@description('Set whether you want your ingress visible externally, or internally within a VNET')
param useExternalIngress bool = false

@description('The port your container listens to for incoming requests. Your application ingress endpoint is always exposed on port 443')
param containerPort int

@description('The resource CPU to Container app. Required CPU in cores, e.g. 0.5 To specify a decimal value, use the json() function.')
param containerResouceCpu string

@description('The resource memory to Container app')
param containerResouceMemory string 

@description('Transport type for Ingress')
@allowed([
  'auto'
  'http'
  'http2'
])
param transportMethod string = 'auto'

@description('Container environment variables.')
param environmentVariables array = []

@description('The number of minimum replicas needed')
param minReplicas int

@description('The number of maximum replicas needed')
param maxReplicas int

@description('ContainerApp resource specific properties')
param workloadProfileName string

var typeOfResource = 'conapp'

var finalResourceName = (resourceName == '') ? ((shortName == '') ? '${namingConventionProperties.subscriptionName}-${namingConventionProperties.projectCode}-${typeOfResource}-${namingConventionProperties.environment}' : '${namingConventionProperties.subscriptionName}-${namingConventionProperties.projectCode}-${typeOfResource}-${shortName}-${namingConventionProperties.environment}' ) : resourceName


resource containerapp 'Microsoft.App/containerapps@2022-11-01-preview' = {
  name: finalResourceName
  location: location
  tags: tags
  identity: {
    type: identityType
  }
  properties: {
    managedEnvironmentId: containerAppEnvironmentName
    configuration: {
      secrets: [
      ]    
      registries: [
      ]
      ingress: {
        external: useExternalIngress
        targetPort: containerPort
        transport: transportMethod
      }
    }
    template: {
      containers: [
        {
          image: containerImage
          name: containerAppName
          env: environmentVariables
          resources: {
            cpu: json(containerResouceCpu)
            memory: containerResouceMemory
          }
        }
      ]
      scale: {
        maxReplicas: maxReplicas
        minReplicas: minReplicas
      }
    }
    workloadProfileName: workloadProfileName
  }
}
```

This is my module call

```
/* 
This Bicep template is used to deploy SonarQube on Azure Containers App.
The resources that are being deployed are:
  - Azure Container App
  - PostgreSQL Flexible Servers
  - PostgreSQL Database
*/
var namingConventionProperties = {
  subscriptionName: ''
  projectCode: ''
  environment: ''
}

param tags object = {
  CreatedVia: ''
  Purpose: ''
}

param location string = resourceGroup().location

var administratorLogin = ''

param sharedVnetName string = ''

param sharedResourceGroupName string = ''

param privEndpointSubnetName string = ''

param privDnsSharedResourceGroup string = ''

param privateDnsZoneName string = ''

param privDnsSubscriptionId string = ''

param charset string = ''

param collation string = ''

@secure()
param administratorLoginPassword string

param dbName string = ''

var containerAppEnvironmentName = ''

var shortName = ''

var postgresqlServerVersion = ''

var skuName = ''

var skuTier = ''

var skuSizeGB = 

var availabilityZone = ''

var identityType = ''

var containerImage = ''

var useExternalIngress = 

var containerPort = 

var containerResouceCpu = ''

var containerResouceMemory = ''

var containerAppName = ''

var transportMethod = ''

var maxReplicas = 

var minReplicas = 

var workloadProfileName = ''


resource containerAppEnvironment 'Microsoft.App/managedEnvironments@2022-11-01-preview' existing = {
  name: containerAppEnvironmentName
}


module postgresql '../../../../../../iac-modules/Infra-As-Code/Modules/Bicep/DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers.bicep' = {
  name: 'postgresql-flexibleServers'
  params: {
    namingConventionProperties: namingConventionProperties
    shortName: shortName
    location: location
    tags: tags
    administratorLogin: administratorLogin
    administratorLoginPassword: administratorLoginPassword
    postgresqlServerVersion: postgresqlServerVersion
    skuName: skuName
    skuTier: skuTier
    skuSizeGB: skuSizeGB
    availabilityZone: availabilityZone
    psqlMetadata : {
      sharedResourceGroup: sharedResourceGroupName
      privEndpointSubnetName: privEndpointSubnetName
      sharedVnetName: sharedVnetName
      pvtDnsZone: {
        resourceGroupName: privDnsSharedResourceGroup
        subscriptionId: privDnsSubscriptionId
        privateDnsZoneName: privateDnsZoneName
      }
    }
  }
}

module database '../../../../../../iac-modules/Infra-As-Code/Modules/Bicep/DBforPostgreSQL/Databases/database.bicep' = {
  name: 'postgresqlDb'
  params: {
    dbName : dbName
    postgresqlName: postgresql.outputs.postgresqlServerName
    charset: charset
    collation: collation
  }
  dependsOn: [
    postgresql
  ]
}

module ContainerApp '../../../../../../iac-modules/Infra-As-Code/Modules/Bicep/ContainerApps/containerApps.bicep' = {
  name: 'ContainerAppDeploy'
  params: {
    namingConventionProperties: namingConventionProperties
    location: location
    tags: tags
    shortName: shortName
    identityType: identityType
    containerAppEnvironmentName: containerAppEnvironment.id
    containerImage: containerImage
    useExternalIngress: useExternalIngress
    containerPort: containerPort
    containerResouceCpu: containerResouceCpu
    containerResouceMemory: containerResouceMemory
    containerAppName: containerAppName
    transportMethod: transportMethod
    environmentVariables: [
      {
        name: 'SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME'
        value: administratorLogin
      }
      {
        name: 'SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD'
        value: administratorLoginPassword
      }
      {
        name: 'SONAR_JDBC_URL'
        value: 'jdbc:postgresql://${postgresql.outputs.postgresqlURL}:5432/sonarqube?user=${administratorLogin}&password=${administratorLoginPassword}&sslmode=require'
        // value: 'jdbc:postgresql://<PSQLEnpointConnectionURL>:5432/<DBName>?user=<UserName>&password=<UserPassword>&sslmode=require'
      }
      // {
      //   name: 'SONAR_SEARCH_JAVAADDITIONALOPTS'
      //   value: '-Dnode.store.allow_mmap=false'
      // }
    ]
      maxReplicas: maxReplicas
      minReplicas: minReplicas
      workloadProfileName: workloadProfileName
  }
  dependsOn: [
    database
  ]
}
```

I tried many options but was unable to figure it out, and the virtual memory space should be increased of host machine and not the container.
Another approach I found a lot of people recommended is `SONAR_SEARCH_JAVAADDITIONALOPTS = -Dnode.store.allow_mmap=false` which ideally should not be done, as it is not suggested for production environment. Using `SONAR_SEARCH_JAVAADDITIONALOPTS = -Dnode.store.allow_mmap=false` will give `OutOfMemoryException` in some cases.

How do I change my `vm.max_map_count` in any case, either through Azure Portal or Bicep automation?

Comment: what's the container resource memory: `containerResouceMemory` ?

Comment: with workload profile `consumption` you can go up to `8Gi` of memory per replica: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/workload-profiles-overview#profile-types

Comment: @Thomas `containerResouceMemory` is a parameter which is used to give the Container Apps memory required which in my case is 60GB. I have used dedicated workload profie with the `Dedicated-E8` series.

Comment: @Thomas Did you have any reference for the above?